# How do I set /usr/local/bin/python version to be 3.9 using update-alternatives?

Tags: python, update-alternatives

`update-alternatives --query python` produces:

```
Name: python
Link: /usr/local/bin/python
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/python3.9
Value: /usr/bin/python3.9

Alternative: /usr/bin/python3
Priority: 0

Alternative: /usr/bin/python3.9
Priority: 1
```

but `python` produces:

```
Python 3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I would like my /usr/local/bin/python to point towards python3.9 and then I can just update my PATH to preference /usr/local/bin

Comment: Python was for python2 which is obsolete. You should never modify that default python3 that comes with the system. But can install as many other python versions as you like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415649/can-i-install-python-3-7-or-later-on-bionic-beaver-18-04